# cache images in service worker in react js progressive-web-app

Tags: reactjs, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am implementing a progressive web app application using react.js lib and i want to customize the service worker and cache the assets images in service worker. how can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
const cacheName = "site-static-v1";

const assets = [
  "/",
  // all files you want to cache
];

// install event
self.addEventListener("install", (evt) => {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
      cache.addAll(assets);
    })
  );
});

// activate event
self.addEventListener("activate", (evt) => {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((keys) => {
      return Promise.all(
        keys.filter((key) => key !== cacheName).map((key) => caches.delete(key))
      );
    })
  );
});

// fetch event
self.addEventListener("fetch", (evt) => {
  evt.respondWith(
    caches
      .match(evt.request)
      .then(
        (cacheRes) =>
          cacheRes || fetch(evt.request).then((fetchRes) => fetchRes)
      )
  );
});
```